# Sequelize Errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, discord.js

I'm new to using Sequelize, I attempted to create a currency system for a Discord Bot game I'm developing. Maybe I'm making the tables entirely wrong, but I thought this method would work for me too. I have a few more files such as dbInit.js, dbObjects.js, and in a models folder I have models/CurrencyShop.js, models/Users.js, models/UserItems.js if you need to see any of those let me know.

Here are the errors:

```
(node:5916) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: users
    at Query.formatError (C:\Users\ryang\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\query.js:422:16)
    at Query._handleQueryResponse (C:\Users\ryang\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\query.js:73:18)
    at afterExecute (C:\Users\ryang\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\query.js:250:31)
    at Statement.errBack (C:\Users\ryang\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:16:21)
(node:5916) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5916) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here is my `app.js` code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();
const { Users, CurrencyShop } = require('./dbObjects');
const { Op } = require('sequelize');
const currency = new Discord.Collection();
const PREFIX = '!';

Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'add', {
    value: async function add(id, amount) {
        const user = currency.get(id);
        if (user) {
            user.balance += Number(amount);
            return user.save();
        }
        const newUser = await Users.create({ user_id: id, balance: amount });
        currency.set(id, newUser);
        return newUser;
    },
});

Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'getBalance', {
    value: function getBalance(id) {
        const user = currency.get(id);
        return user ? user.balance : 0;
    },
});

client.once('ready', async () => {
    const storedBalances = await Users.findAll();
    storedBalances.forEach(b => currency.set(b.user_id, b));
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    currency.add(message.author.id, 1);

    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
    const input = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim();
    if (!input.length) return;
    const [, command, commandArgs] = input.match(/(\w+)\s*([\s\S]*)/);

    if (command === 'balance') {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        return message.channel.send(`${target.tag} has ${currency.getBalance(target.id)}`);
    } else if (command === 'inventory') {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        const user = await Users.findOne({ where: { user_id: target.id } });
        const items = await user.getItems();

        if (!items.length) return message.channel.send(`${target.tag} has nothing!`);
        return message.channel.send(`${target.tag} currently has ${items.map(i => `${i.amount} ${i.item.name}`).join(', ')}`);
    } else if (command === 'transfer') {
        const currentAmount = currency.getBalance(message.author.id);
        const transferAmount = commandArgs.split(/ +/g).find(arg => !/<@!?\d+>/g.test(arg));
        const transferTarget = message.mentions.users.first();

        if (!transferAmount || isNaN(transferAmount)) return message.channel.send(`Sorry ${message.author}, that's an invalid amount.`);
        if (transferAmount > currentAmount) return message.channel.send(`Sorry ${message.author}, you only have ${currentAmount}.`);
        if (transferAmount <= 0) return message.channel.send(`Please enter an amount greater than zero, ${message.author}.`);

        currency.add(message.author.id, -transferAmount);
        currency.add(transferTarget.id, transferAmount);

        return message.channel.send(`Successfully transferred ${transferAmount} to ${transferTarget.tag}. Your current balance is ${currency.getBalance(message.author.id)}`);
    } else if (command === 'buy') {
        const item = await CurrencyShop.findOne({ where: { name: { [Op.like]: commandArgs } } });
        if (!item) return message.channel.send(`That item doesn't exist.`);
        if (item.cost > currency.getBalance(message.author.id)) {
            return message.channel.send(`You currently have ${currency.getBalance(message.author.id)}, but the ${item.name} costs ${item.cost}!`);
        }

        const user = await Users.findOne({ where: { user_id: message.author.id } });
        currency.add(message.author.id, -item.cost);
        await user.addItem(item);

        message.channel.send(`You've bought: ${item.name}.`);
    } else if (command === 'shop') {
        const items = await CurrencyShop.findAll();
        return message.channel.send(items.map(item => `${item.name}: ${item.cost}`).join('\n'), { code: true });
    } else if (command === 'leaderboard') {
        return message.channel.send(
        currency.sort((a, b) => b.balance - a.balance)
            .filter(user => client.users.has(user.user_id))
            .first(10)
            .map((user, position) => `(${position + 1}) ${(client.users.get(user.user_id).tag)}: ${user.balance}`)
            .join('\n'),
        { code: true }
        );
    }
});

client.login('Njc4MTM2MzY1NTE0MzU4Nzg0.XkxHOQ.mx9sBQt0BlLlcCKn1NKP_GnbhIY');
```

I'd appreciate either documentation, videos, or an explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use [try-catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

```
 client.on('message', async message => {
    try{

       if (message.author.bot) return;
        currency.add(message.author.id, 1);

        if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
        const input = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim();
        if (!input.length) return;
        const [, command, commandArgs] = input.match(/(\w+)\s*([\s\S]*)/);

        if (command === 'balance') {
            const target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
            return message.channel.send(`${target.tag} has ${currency.getBalance(target.id)}`);
        } else if (command === 'inventory') {
            const target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
            const user = await Users.findOne({ where: { user_id: target.id } });
            const items = await user.getItems();

            if (!items.length) return message.channel.send(`${target.tag} has nothing!`);
            return message.channel.send(`${target.tag} currently has ${items.map(i => `${i.amount} ${i.item.name}`).join(', ')}`);
        } else if (command === 'transfer') {
            const currentAmount = currency.getBalance(message.author.id);
            const transferAmount = commandArgs.split(/ +/g).find(arg => !/<@!?\d+>/g.test(arg));
            const transferTarget = message.mentions.users.first();

            if (!transferAmount || isNaN(transferAmount)) return message.channel.send(`Sorry ${message.author}, that's an invalid amount.`);
            if (transferAmount > currentAmount) return message.channel.send(`Sorry ${message.author}, you only have ${currentAmount}.`);
            if (transferAmount <= 0) return message.channel.send(`Please enter an amount greater than zero, ${message.author}.`);

            currency.add(message.author.id, -transferAmount);
            currency.add(transferTarget.id, transferAmount);

            return message.channel.send(`Successfully transferred ${transferAmount} to ${transferTarget.tag}. Your current balance is ${currency.getBalance(message.author.id)}`);
        } else if (command === 'buy') {
            const item = await CurrencyShop.findOne({ where: { name: { [Op.like]: commandArgs } } });
            if (!item) return message.channel.send(`That item doesn't exist.`);
            if (item.cost > currency.getBalance(message.author.id)) {
                return message.channel.send(`You currently have ${currency.getBalance(message.author.id)}, but the ${item.name} costs ${item.cost}!`);
            }

            const user = await Users.findOne({ where: { user_id: message.author.id } });
            currency.add(message.author.id, -item.cost);
            await user.addItem(item);

            message.channel.send(`You've bought: ${item.name}.`);
        } else if (command === 'shop') {
            const items = await CurrencyShop.findAll();
            return message.channel.send(items.map(item => `${item.name}: ${item.cost}`).join('\n'), { code: true });
        } else if (command === 'leaderboard') {
            return message.channel.send(
            currency.sort((a, b) => b.balance - a.balance)
                .filter(user => client.users.has(user.user_id))
                .first(10)
                .map((user, position) => `(${position + 1}) ${(client.users.get(user.user_id).tag)}: ${user.balance}`)
                .join('\n'),
            { code: true }
            );
        }

    }catch(err){
     // handle all error here 
     // Like SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: users
       console.log(err)
    }

    });
```

Comment: Is something new supposed to pop up in the console? I am getting the exact same errors as before. They aren't stacked any different either.

Comment: first `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` which you need to handle so how you handle that i have shown you and second error is "SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: users" so please check if "users" table exists in database

Comment: I do have a database.sqlite file in my directory, but it is empty. Would I check for the table like this?:

SELECT 1 FROM schema_name.table_name LIMIT 0;

If so, where do I put it?

Comment: which database you are using

Comment: I thought Sequelize would make the database with the different form of tables I made. Such as const newUser = await Users.create({ user_id: id, balance: amount });

Comment: `client.once('ready', async () => { const storedBalances = await Users.findAll();` check this

Comment: Ok, just tried that and got a different error: https://gyazo.com/35dd59f00552d28ecdd1c57f3950533d

Comment: Not sure if I need a mySQL database or something, really new to databases and such.

Comment: Please ask a new question related to the database issue

Comment: I think it's bad practice to surround so much code in a try-catch, it should be used for smaller pieces of code that specifiically throw an error you wish to catch & handle.